# How can I recover lost Contacts on Galaxy GT-NT7000. Contacts and Dialer App became very slow and battery runs down fast,

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, contacts, battery-life, data-recovery, phone-app

This is a RAM issue and lost contacts issue (contacts not saved under Google). The log of text messages with all contacts, since start, is all, still there. My Android version is 4.2.1. I have had 3.5 GB available on the internal storage and only 170 MB on the device memory; I was under the impression that pictures and images since they are stored at the internal storage, they do not affect the processing (is that called RAM same as in PCs or not?) speed, but that was wrong. I have moved all pictures and videos from phone to my PC to make more space but after having moved all the pictures/videos, on day before I have lost all my Phone Contacts! The speed of navigating and of using the dialer and of Contacts (these apps were worse affected in terms of speed) and even the battery life has improved a lot, yet I still need to find more space (by emptying the SIM card), but I await to take the phone to a repair centre to be seen first.

400 or so contacts were saved under 'Phone Contacts'' and they are all gone. Since 350 of my Contacts were saved primarily under Google (Gmail), I have not lost all Contacts but another I called Samsung Support service and they advised me to visit a Geek Squad Carphone warehouse which is authorised to service Samsung-Android devices. Should I do this first to be on the safe side, or should  I download the Dr. Fone for Android app and try to bring back the Contacts? Does anyone have experience with Dr Fone? http://www.wondershare.net/disk-utility/recover-contacts-from-samsung.html?gclid=CJTkyPLpwboCFfHKtAodpngArA

Comment: Hi kostas, I'm having a hard time understanding your issue. What did you exactly do to move the pics and videos? Moving files around should be completely unrelated to losing your contacts, they're not accessible if you don't have rooted your phone. Can you explain what you did? How / when did you notice the loss?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Samsung customer service advised me yesterday to export my Contacts to the sim card; he felt that by doing so the non Google contacts would appear on the phone (how on earth I do not know!), but they did not. The images and videos I moved them to my PC, as advised, by connecting with a USB cable and dragging the whole camera file from the phone to my PC. I only did this to make more space in the phone as ALREADY the Contacts were removed-lost the day before w/out me doing or moving anything and w/out even realising. Now I see a ''storage running out'' message!

Comment: So you've lost all your contacts before you moved the video/picture files? Internally, contacts are stored in an sqlite3 database which is known to be very safe (there exist only a few ways of corrupting it http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html and none of it is the fault of sqlite3). It's very probably your flash chip that corrupted it. There's alas nothing you can do if that is the case. Be sure to store all contacts on Google or make frequent backups in the future... Sorry.

Comment: Thank you ce4. I am not technical, but by reading fast your link on sqlite, it is possible that the background sync of images in Drop Box and of Contacts in Google, running automatically may have interfered? hence the flash chip ref? do you suggest that I set syncs at regular intervals or it does not matter? Btw, even after removing all images, I have only 200MB of space available in the device memory, so I will need to remove more applications but only just a couple are not Googleplay and hence can be removed. Removing some to the SD card not possible (no space). Can I add extra SD card?

Comment: Btw, for other readers with data recovery issues: I came across this free software: http://www.icare-recovery.com/free/android-data-recovery-freeware.html

Comment: You did lose all of your contacts, i.e. suddenly your address book was empty. right? It's probably irrevocably gone then. Regarding the sqlite3 site: This is only tech background info to illustrate how robust the storing facility is. Changing sync intervals etc. is irrelevant. It was just meant to illustrate that this should never happen unless there's a hardware problem or a really serious bug in Android (which i doubt).